# C-Macros produces unexpected behavior

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, precompile, pre-compilation

I'm trying to make my header file easily changeable with macros. I'm debugging my code and it seems these MACROS are not doing what they are supposed to. Can someone tell me how I achieve the following effect? LED_ID_AMS etc.

```
#define LED_NUMBER                  (2)
#define LED_ID_X                    (0)
#define LED_ID_Y                    (1)
#define LED_PIN_X                   (0)
#define LED_PIN_Y                   (3)
#define LED_PORT_X                  (PORTE)
#define LED_PORT_Y                  (PORTG)
#define LED_DD_X                    (DDRE)
#define LED_DD_Y                    (DDRG)
#define LED_PORT(LED_ID_X)          (LED_PORT_X)
#define LED_PORT(LED_ID_Y)          (LED_PORT_Y)
#define LED_PIN(LED_ID_X)           (LED_PIN_X)
#define LED_PIN(LED_ID_Y)           (LED_PIN_Y)
#define LED_DD(LED_ID_X)            (LED_DD_X)
#define LED_DD(LED_ID_Y)            (LED_DD_Y)
```

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I'm trying to make it so I can loop through the port init like so:

```
for(i=0;i<LED_NUMBER;i++){
    /* set data direction to output*/
    LED_DD(i)|=((0x01)<<LED_PIN(i));
    /* turn on led */
    LED_PORT(i)|=((0x01)<<LED_PIN(i));
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a harsh response I'm getting here... not how I remember stackoverflow. I admit it was not all too specific. I've added some details.

Comment: Well now your question's understandable at least. Do you really need macros though? Plain old arrays couldn't work?

Comment: I want to do it with precompiler directives so its easily modify and as much happens at precompile time as possible

Comment: but seeing the question was downvoted to -2 already I probably have no chance at getting a reasonable answer now...

Comment: Thing is the pre-compiler doesn't know about your runtime `for` loop. It's only parsing the body once, so you'll get only one substitution. Either that involves an array index/pointer arithmetic or some other calculation based on `i`, or your idea won't work. Those things cannot be fixed at compile time with the pre-processor combined with a runtime `for` loop. There's tricks to do loops with the pre-processor, but that's arcane magic as far as I'm concerned. Try something simple first, optimize if it happens to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I've added some more, so you see what I mean. I will come away from using macros like you suggest I think.

Comment: I'm missing a definition of the LED_DD(x) macro your using in the first statement within the loop body?

Comment: @mfro it was missing, now its complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will regret using too many macros later. Actually, you're regretting it already, as they don't work and, being macros, they are very difficult to debug.

Just a few points:

- your `LED_PIN(i)` expressions are always expanding to `0`
- your `LED_PORT(i)` expressions are always expanding to `PORTE` whatever that may be

For instance `LED_PIN(LED_ID_X)` expands to `LED_PIN_X`. Note, macro parameter `LED_ID_X` is not used at all. Instead, `LED_PIN_X` simply expands to `0`.

Comment: tell me if point 1 & 2 still hold true for the changes I've added and I'll accept you're answer and be happy man

Comment: Yes, my 2 points are still valid after the changes. I'll explain in the answer why.

Comment: I had fergotten to add a few lines, now its complete, I would appreciate if you looked at it one more time.

Comment: It's getting worse. Now you have multiple macros with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add at least one of:

- arrays
- inline functions
- more complicated macros

And it also seems to me that dereferencing of hardware addresses will be required.

For example, using macros, you can define:

```
#define LED_PORT(i) *(uint16_t *)( \
    (i) == LED_ID_X ? LED_PORT_X : \
    (i) == LED_ID_Y ? LED_PORT_Y : \
    etc)
```

where:

```
#define LED_ID_X     (0)
#define LED_ID_Y     (1)
#define LED_PORT_X   (PORTE)
#define LED_PORT_Y   (PORTG)
#define PORTE        (0x11112222U) // example only
#define PORTG        (0x33334444U) // example only
```

Here `uint16_t` is only a guess: I'm assuming 16-bit ports in a 32-bit address space.

Or, using arrays and C99's designated initializers:

```
const uint32_t LED_PORT[] = {
    [LED_ID_X] = LED_PORT_X,
    [LED_ID_Y] = LED_PORT_Y
};

#define LED_PORT(i) (*(uint16_t *)LED_PORT[i])
```

And of course, without C99 you can use just:

```
const uint32_t LED_PORT[] = {LED_PORT_X, LED_PORT_Y};
```

which *assumes* that `LED_ID_X` is `0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should scream warnings at you, as e.g. `LED_PORT(SOME_ARG)` has several definitions. And in `LED_PORT(LED_ID_X)` the `LED_ID_X` is just a dummy argument, with absolutely no relation to your constant `LED_ID_X`.

You can make your code equally readable by using a constant array, perhaps used from macros like you try to do here.

Unless there are a *massive* number of `LED_ID_<foo>`, this is at best a minor simplification. Don't do that. If there is a lot of code futzing around with those is mostly the same way, it might make sense to define a macro that iterates some action over each of them, i.e.:

```
#define FROB_LEDS \\
     action(LED_ID_X); \\
     action(LED_ID_Y); \\
     action(LED_ID_Z);
```

and define `action(X)` locally as a macro to do the action on LED `X`, `FROB` them, and undefine `action` again. Quite ugly, true.